# миллисекундомер?

Tags: javascript, jquery

знатоки нужно сделать **миллисекундомер** на **javascript**.  Т.е. функция которая начинает считать и другая функция которая остановит счет и вставит результат в другой блок.

Что то на подобии вот такого:

```js
var time=0;
function timeView(){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = time;
    time++;
    setTimeout("timeView()", 100);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="timeView()">
<div id=a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Только с кнопкой **стоп** и вставлять результат в другой **div** блок.

Comment: Вы где этот код взяли? Сомневаюсь что сами написали, иначе и ответ дался бы очень легко

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы в своём вопросе и дали ответ.

```js
var time = 0;
var hTimer = null;

function startTimer() {
  if (hTimer) {
    hTimer = clearInterval(hTimer);
  } else {
    hTimer = setInterval(updateTimer, 100);
  }
}

function resetTimer() {
  time = 0;
}

function updateTimer() {
  document.getElementById('a').textContent = ++time;
}

function copyTimer() {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = time;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body >
  <div id=a></div>
  <div>Result:
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
  <button onClick="startTimer()">Start/Stop</button>
  <button onClick="resetTimer()">Reset</button>
  <button onClick="copyTimer()">Copy</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно! Только если на паузе, ресить не получается...

Comment: Вызови updateTimer в ресете

Comment: В неактивыной вкладке будет работать неверно. Да и вообще, работает неточно.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const t = document.getElementById('start-n-stop'),
      x = document.getElementById('x'),
      y = document.getElementById('y')
f = onclick = e => {
  (d = new Date()),
  (f ? itv = setInterval("x.textContent=(new Date-d)/1e3") : clearInterval(itv))
  f = !f
  if (t.textContent === 'Start') {
    t.textContent = 'Stop'
  } else {
    t.textContent = 'Start';
    y.textContent += '\n' + x.textContent
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.millisecond-stopwatch {
  display: flex;
}

#a {
  height: 1rem;
}

#start-n-stop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#output {
  display: flex;
  border: 0.0625rem dashed;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 3rem;
}

#output>div {
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
}

#output>div:first-child {
  border-right: 0.0625rem dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="start-n-stop">Start</div>
<div class="millisecond-stopwatch">
</div>
<div id="output">
  <div id="x"></div>
  <div id="y"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня рекорд 0.06)

Comment: @ThisMan, 0.061 XD (this isn't sarcasm)

Comment: Лучше использовать `performance.now()`

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен пожалуй, хорошие новости, я остаюсь, но посещение моё резко упадёт

Comment: @Arthur, это отлично! :)